# Using selenium to access attribute text

Tags: html, selenium, attributes, href

I'm really new to selenium and this is probably really simple, but what i'm trying to do is store the '2017 League Table Ranking: 25th" text inside this attribute to a string in java:

```
<a href="/league-tables/rankings">
 2017 League Table Ranking: 25th
</a>

public void findRanking() throws Exception {
  String ranking = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(@href, '/league-tables/rankings')])")).getAttribute(href) ;

}
```

This gives me the link to the href that the attribute is using, and is the closest i've got to getting an output kind of right. I've tried simply getting the text of the element above, using the .getText() method but that returns nothing, where am i going wrong?

Comment: Can you post a link to the page?

Comment: https://www.thecompleteuniversityguide.co.uk/newcastle/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we now have a link to the page, I was able to create a unique locator. The problem was that there was more than one element that matched the locator and the first match wasn't the one you wanted. Since we don't need XPath here, I switched to a CSS selector. CSS selectors have better browser support, are faster, and I think are easier to create. This should work now.

```
public String findRanking() {
    return driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("p.league-table-latest-rank > a[href='/league-tables/rankings']")).getText();
}
```

Here are some references for CSS selectors. I would suggest that you spend some time learning them. They are extremely powerful and should be your goto locator after `By.id()`.

[W3C CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)

[Sauce Labs CSS Selector Tips](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors)

---

Original answer with XPath

`.getText()` should work on that element. It looks like you have an extra set of () in your XPath. Also, you should be able to use equals instead of `contains()`. There may be other links that contain that partial href that may be causing issues. I would try the below. I added a `return` and changed the return type to `String`.

```
public String findRanking() {
    return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/league-tables/rankings']")).getText();
}
```

You can test your XPath in Chrome. Open the page and try `$x("//a[@href='/league-tables/rankings']").length` in the dev console and make sure it returns `1`. If it's `0` then something is wrong with the locator. If it's `> 1` then you'll have to further narrow the focus of your locator. Find a unique parent that has an ID or something unique.

Comment: I think my locator must be wrong because even with this it still isn't returning anything

Comment: Did you try `$x()` as I suggested?

Comment: yep it turned out as 3, i see now, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public String findRanking(){
   WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, '/league-tables/rankings')]");
   return e.getText();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

If you want to get the `text` of `2017 League Table Ranking: 25th` then use below code.

```
String test = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), '2017 League Table Ranking: 25th')]")).getText();
System.out.println(test);
```

If you want to get the `href` attribute of this text `2017 League Table Ranking: 25th` then use below code.

```
String href = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), '2017 League Table Ranking: 25th')]")).getAttribute("href");
System.out.println(href);
```

Comment: turns out my locator was wrong, JeffC's solution fixed it, thanks though!

Comment: It's not about locator issue, you can do same thing with different approach as well. Like @Jeffc doing with `cssSelector` and I am doing with `xpath locator`. From both these locators you will be getting your result.

Comment: If this answer is `helpful` to you, then please mark this answer as `Accepted`